# Force closed source application to use Direct3DDevice9Ex instead of non-Ex device

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

Basically what I want to do is force a closed source application which uses a `Direct3D9Ex` context `(CreateD3D9Ex)` but a simple "non-ex" device `(IDirect3DDevice9)` to use a `Direct3DDevice9Ex` instead. 
I placed a proxy dll inside the application directory which in general works fine. Now I am trying to redirect the call for `CreateDevice` to the original dll's  `CreateDeviceEx` and then just return a "non-ex" pointer (so that the application uses an "Ex" device without knowing about it).

To my understanding this should work because the "Ex" device implements all methods the "non-ex" device also contains - but apparently there must be some difference, because the only thing which gets rendered if the hidden "Ex" device is in use is the cursor.

**Q:** Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or give some advice?

**Background**

I am using a `D3D9` application of which I want to copy the depth buffer. Unfortunately its format is `D24S8` which implicates that a direct copy is impossible.

So I decided to try if it is possible to create a shared depth/stencil 1-level texture and then access this texture with the `D3D10/D3D11` methods that are in fact capable of copying depth/stencil surfaces. However, only `D3D9Ex` devices are able to create textures with shared handles...

**Appendix**

Due to the fact Direct3D9Ex does not support the managed pool it is not possible. Thanks @VuVirt

Comment: I did raise the same [question](https://github.com/elishacloud/dxwrapper/discussions/105) to a wrapper fixes developer, and at the end of the day I came up with the impression that due to a bunch of *Ex* limitations upgrading to a different but more "powerful" api could actually give you a better time in the long run (even though, if you only care for a single application just focusing on debugging/reversing that specifically should be far smoother). FWIW dxup, dxvk and reshade all convert `D3DFMT_D24S8` to whatever the equivalent `D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` (or `D32_SFLOAT_S8_UINT` if any) they have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is mainly caused by the fact that the D3D9Ex device doesn't support D3DPOOL_MANAGED resources. That's the reason why you don't see anything rendered on the screen. The resource creation with D3DPOOL_MANAGED will actually fail. You may want to hook all the resource creation routines as well and remove the [D3DPOOL_MANAGED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172584(v=vs.85).aspx) flag from the calls and optionally add [D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172625(v=vs.85).aspx) if someone wants to Lock them. This however, might cause another set of problems. Search for "Differences between Direct3D 9 and Direct3D 9Ex" in the provided MSDN links.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think about that part. Well, time for the next approach ;) Thanks anyway.